# How to dynamically format a number with thousand separators in a `\TextField` of a fillable pdf?

Tags: pdf

I'm using LaTeX to create a PDF form and would like to display numbers in text fields (`\TextField`) with thousand separators. For example, converting "5000000" to "5,000,000". Here is the code for my field:

```latex
\TextField[
    name=nominal,
    align=1,
    value={5000000}
]{}
```

I know how to set custom formats for dates in LaTeX using:

```latex
\newcommand{\mydateformat}{AFDate_FormatEx("dd/mm/yyyy");}
\newcommand{\mykeystroke}{AFDate_KeystrokeEx("dd/mm/yyyy");}

\TextField[
     name=debutCommercialisation,
     align=1,
     value={19/3/2024},
     format={\mydateformat},
     keystroke={\mykeystroke}
]{}
```

However, I haven't found an equivalent way to format numbers with thousand separators directly in LaTeX. I'm aware that JavaScript scripts can be used to achieve this goal in PDFs, but I'm unsure how to integrate such scripts into a PDF generated by LaTeX, or if it's even possible.

1. Is it possible to dynamically format numbers with thousand separators in a `\TextField` directly via LaTeX?
2. If not, is there a method to embed custom JavaScript in a PDF generated by LaTeX to accomplish this formatting?

I'm open to any suggestions or alternative solutions.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{Form}

\TextField[
    name=nominal,
    align=1,
    value=5000000 
]{}

\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

NB : @Ulrike Fischer I'm sure you have the answer to this :)

Comment: well as you know me, you should also know that I don't like questions without complete example.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer MWE added

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand{\myformat}{AFNumber_Format(2, 0, 0, 0, "", true);}
\newcommand{\mykeystroke}{AFNumber_KeystrokeEx(2, 0, 0, 0, "", true);}

\begin{document}
\begin{Form}

\TextField[
    name=nominal,
    align=1,
    value=5000000,
    format=\myformat,
    keystroke=\mykeystroke 
]{}

\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The source of the format https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/experience-manager-learn/assets/FormsAPIReference.pdf?lang=en ?