# How to implement conditional fields in fillable PDF forms created in LaTeX?

Tags: pdf, textfield

Following this question [How to dynamically format a number with thousand separators in a `\TextField` of a fillable pdf?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/713558/163874)
My goal now is to have certain fields appear or become hidden based on the user's selection from a dropdown menu. For example, if the user selects "Single stock" from the dropdown, a field for entering the "Name of the underlying" should appear. Similarly, different fields should appear for other selections like "Index decrement" or "Stock decrement".

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{Form}
\ChoiceMenu[combo,name=typeSousJacent,width=10cm]{}{%
    Single stock,
    Index decrement,
    Stock decrement,
} \\

Nom du sous-jacent: \TextField[name=sousJacent,width=5cm]{} \\
Ticker: \TextField[name=ticker]{} \\
Decrement: \CheckBox[name=decrementyesno,width=1em]{} \\
Niveau de decrement: \TextField[name=decrement]{}
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

I tried the following but with not much success

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[pdftex]{insdljs}

\begin{insDLJS}[showhidejs]{showhide}{Show/Hide Fields}
function updateFields()  {
    var typeSousJacentValue = this.getField("typeSousJacent").value;
    this.getField("sousJacent").display = (typeSousJacentValue == "Single stock") ? display.visible : display.hidden;
    this.getField("ticker").display = (typeSousJacentValue == "Single stock" || typeSousJacentValue == "Stock decrement") ? display.visible : display.hidden;

}
\end{insDLJS}

\begin{document}
\begin{Form}
\ChoiceMenu[combo,name=typeSousJacent,onchange={updateFields();},width=10cm]{}{% No action here when opend on acrobat
    Single stock,
    Index decrement,
    Stock decrement,
} \\

Nom du sous-jacent: \TextField[name=sousJacent,width=5cm]{} \\
Ticker: \TextField[name=ticker]{} \\
Decrement: \CheckBox[name=decrementyesno,width=1em]{} \\
Niveau de decrement: \TextField[name=decrement]{}
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

Is there a way to achieve to dynamically show/hide fields based on the dropdown selection ?

Comment: `Following a previous question on fillable pdf`: it's a big site.

Comment: @cfr agreed :) link added.

Comment: that is not really a TeX question but a question about javascript for PDF form fields. You should better ask/search on sites which discuss form fields - once you know the needed javascript/field options it is then rather easy to add that to the LaTeX code.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thank you, i'll do that and edit when/if i have an answer.

Comment: If you cross-post the same question on multiple sites, you should include links to all other versions of the question in every question. X-posting without explicit links has the risk of wasting both the time of users who might put time and effort into answering a post, which already has an answer elsewhere, as well as the time of users who might have the same problem but can't find the solutions you might have gotten on one of the other sites you x-posted your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some struggle, I found that neither `onChoice()` nor `onchange()` actually exist in the `adobe pdf sdk`. However `onblur` and `onfocus` could be used.
The condition on `index` rather than `text` in the combobox simplifies everything...

Still one question though... I'd like the labels to be hidden too...

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[pdftex]{insdljs}

    \begin{insDLJS}[showhidejs]{showhide}{Show/Hide Fields}
    
    function updateFields() {
        var typeSousJacentIndex = this.getField("typeSousJacent").currentValueIndices;
        // Mask these fields by default
        this.getField("decrementyesno").display = display.hidden;
        this.getField("decrement").display = display.hidden;
    
        // Display fields based on selection
        if(typeSousJacentIndex == 1 || typeSousJacentIndex == 2) { // Single stock ou Stock decrement
            this.getField("decrementyesno").display = display.visible;
            this.getField("decrement").display = display.visible;
        }
    }
    
    \end{insDLJS}
    
    \begin{document}
    \begin{Form}
    
    \ChoiceMenu[combo,name=typeSousJacent,width=10cm,onfocus={updateFields();},onblur={updateFields();}]{}{
        Single stock,
        Index decrement,
        Stock decrement,
    } 
    
    \TextField[name=sousJacent,width=5cm]{Nom du sous-jacent:} 
    
    \TextField[name=ticker]{Ticker :} 
    
    \CheckBox[name=decrementyesno,width=1em]{Decrement:}
    
    \TextField[name=decrement,width=2cm]{Niveau de decrement:}
    
    \end{Form}
    \end{document}
```